# How to signal the caller thread that ExecutorService has finished a task

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

From the main thread:

```
executorService.submit(new Runnable() { ... });
```

Now when Runnable has finished executing, is there the Java's standard way of signaling the caller thread that it has finished executing, without making a new interface/listener class?

Bonus points if the signal can be emitted from the caller thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`submit` returns a [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) on which the submitting thread can call [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) to block until the task completes.

```
Future<?> future = executor.submit(new Runnable() { ... });
future.get();
```

Comment: If I use future.get(), the caller thread has to consciously call that to see if it's done.  The caller thread in my app happens to be a UI thread which can't have any blocking operations, but it'd need to receive some sort of update when to refresh the views.

Comment: You'll need to submit a task to the UI thread to run upon completion. The UI thread's event loop will pick up the task and run it. Or you could schedule a recurring task in the UI thread to poll the future regularly until `isDone` returns `true`.

Answer (score 3):

You can block on get() of the Future object that is returned, or poll the isDone() method on it. Alternatively, you could use the google guava library that has [ListenableFuture](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html).

Comment: I am pretty sure that get() blocks until the the computation has completed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your implementation and how many threads will be running simultaneously, so this may not work. One thing you could take a look at is to have the runnable itsself signal it is completed by calling a method that knows how to update the UI component that is needed.